# what is (overrides) in objective c

Tags: objective-c, overriding

I'm following a tutorial on how to create a popover in Iphone [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iykxemuxbk)

what is `(overrides)` this code:

```
@interface UIPopoverController (overrides)
  + (BOOL)_popoversDisabled;
@end

@implementation UIPopoverController (overrides)

  + (BOOL)_popoversDisabled 
  { 
     return NO;
  }

@end
```

Comment: google `objective c category`

Comment: See http://bit.ly/15CpGqI

Comment: @Zéychin How would you search for that without already knowing that this is the syntax for Objective-C categories? Googling for `overrides` probably won't be all that helpful...

Comment: "overrides" is just an arbitrary string of characters, actually.  It indicates a category and ties the particular category's interface to its corresponding implementation, but "means" nothing otherwise.  Could just as well have been "a7ipqnt".

Comment: just found this great explanation on categories: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/learn-objective-c-day-6/ and for c#pers like me category = extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an objective-C category. A category is a way of providing extra methods on a class, and they're useful in the following situations:

- Extending a library class with domain-specific functionality. ie providing some extra features that will be useful for your application. This works whether or not you have the source-code for that class. For example, you could implement an **[NSString asCreditCard]** method or **[UIColor applicationThemeColor]**.
- Categories are also invaluable for grouping related functionality in a complex class.

Objective-C categories have the restriction that you cannot define additional ivars, and thus ivar-backed properties, on a category, although you can easily work around this using *associative references* - a run-time feature allowing you to link an object to a given class.

**Associative References**

To 'fake' a property or ivar on a category class use the following:

Define a 'key' to reference the associated property.

```
static char const* const carNamekey = "com.myObject.aKey";
```

The key doesn't necessarily have to have a value, since its the memory address of the object that is actually used.

Now, Implement the properties:

```
- (void) setCar:(Car*)car 
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &carNamekey, car, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);     
}

- (Car*) car 
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &carNamekey);
}
```

If you wish you can add an @property declaration on the interface definition for the category, as an invitation to users of the class to use property-style (ie class.property = xxx) syntax.

**Class Extensions**

Another feature that is very similar to Objective-C categories is the class extension. A class extension is defined in the implementation block for a class like so:

```
@interface MyClass()
```

Some people refer to these as 'empty categories', but this is not quite correct. Unlike a category, a class extension will allow you to define additional properties and ivars on a class, without using associative references. This is useful for making a readonly property, internally writable, and things like that.

There - now you probably know more about categories than a lot of folks :)

Comment: Categories can introduce properties; properties are just a different kind of method declaration. They cannot _synthesize_ or otherwise add an ivar for property , but the declaration itself is not illegal.

Answer (score 3):

Jasper Blues' answer explains categories nicely, so I'll just add that you should avoid using categories to override methods in the class to which you're adding the category. The reason is that the order in which categories are added to a class is undefined, so you can't know for certain whether the class will get your version of a method or one defined in another category. **If you need to override methods in a class, create a subclass and put your overrides there.**

However, people sometimes use categories to organize the methods in a class definition. If that's the case here, the method(s) in the `overrides` category are probably meant to override methods in the superclass, which is fine.